# UIAccessibility is not selecting correct elements

Tags: uikit, uiwindow, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have several `UIWindows` in my app. Some `UIWindows` have very high window levels. i.e.

```
window.windowLevel = currentWindowLevel+1;
```

For some reason when turning on accessibility support, the system insists on reading out the accessibility labels of views located in the lower level window, even in cases where the views aren't even visible.

This minimal example exemplifies this behavior.

With accessibility support turned on, try to press the label in the red window. The system will read out the text from the underneath table view instead

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableview.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableview registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIWindow *w = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        w.windowLevel = self.view.window.windowLevel + 1;
        w.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        w.hidden = NO;
        w.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        l.text = @"KUKUKUKUKUKUKUKLU";
        [l sizeToFit];
        l.frame = CGRectOffset(l.frame, 40, 100);
        [w addSubview:l];
        w.accessibilityLabel = @"Read this outloud instead";
        static id window;
        window = w;
    });

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 100;
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thats irrelevant to the question. I supplied an answer in any case

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to set the attribute

```
Window.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;
```